# Detecting bad characters in URL parameters

Tags: php, url, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

I've been getting logs in my error log, which I've tracked down to be a problem with bad characters being send as URL parameters. My problem is that i don't know how to detect those in my code to be able to return a proper error message.

This is the parameter that is making a mess:

```
%E2%80%A2%C2%B0$%CallmeG.G%25$%C2%B0%E2%80%A2&name%5B35%5D
```

After urldecoding, this will be:

```
•°$�llmeG.G%$°•
```

I can see that something goes wrong here with the "�". Which is the only character messing up my code. However I am not sure how to detect this or help the problem.

Comment: Have you try [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-var.php) function ?

Comment: Which filter do you suggest?

Comment: You can try with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you

```
urldecode('%Ca');
```

the output is

```
�
```

You need to remove (or escape) the '%' preceding 'Ca'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am not really looking for a way to decode this single example. The input comes from users, so I am looking for a way to handle errors when users send badly encoded parameters.

Comment: Can you automatically escape '%'?